# For Command help - nested command

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, command-prompt

I have created the following simple batch file.... What I'm trying to accomplish here is to connect using Remote Command (RCMD utility) to a list o servers defined in (clusters.txt) and delete a list of video files difines in (assets.txt)... I want to delete those assets on every server. This Batch file works however it has to connect and disconnect to delete every piece of asset and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I want to be able to connect to 1 server and delete my list of assets %%B using scp del cmd then disconnect from that server and go to the next one on the list %%A and delete all the assets from there with just one connection instead of having to connect and disconnect 200 times.

```
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (clusters.txt) DO FOR /F "tokens=*" %%B in (assets.txt) DO rcmd \\%%A \vstrmkit\scp del %%B
```

This is what the list of files looks like:

```
11E8A51A*
11E8A51D*
11E8A614*
11E88E4E*
11E88E4C*
```

and the list of server it's just computer hostnames with letters and numbers:

```
SEA88630-N0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you just have one line in "your list of files" file and in your "servers  name" file ? or is one value=one line ?

Comment: Sachadee, I have one line per server and per file, so I have about 30 Servers (1 per line) and 120 files (120 lines, 1 per file).

Comment: What is the OS of the client and servers?

Comment: @MC ND this is **Windows server 2003**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the server and client versions of the OS, it is possible to have some kind of command line limitations. But, let's try

```
@echo off

    rem prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Define the command that will be executed for each element
    set "command=echo \vstrmkit\scp del"

    rem Prepare the command for the list of files into a environment variable
    set "command=set c=%command% "
    for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (assets.txt) do set "command=!command!/@c@%%~f"

    rem Adjust the command variable to generate a valid concatenation of commands
    set "command=%command:/=&%"

    rem Connect to each of the servers sending the generated command
    rem In the last step, change the @ with ! to generate on remote, when
    rem delayed expansion is applied, the correct final command to execute
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion    
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (clusters.txt) do rcmd \\%%a cmd.exe /v:on /c "%command:@=!%"
```

Note that the line where the main command in defined, there is a `echo` inserted for testing. If everything seems ok, remove `echo` to do it work.

EDITED - Option number 2

It seems that there is some problem with quotes. The previous code works in my system but not in the OP. Let's try another one. It also works on my system.

```
@echo off

    rem prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Define the command that will be executed for each element
    set "command=echo \vstrmkit\scp del"

    rem Define a temporary file to contain commands to process
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.tmp"

    rem Generate the content of the temp file with the list of commands
    rem to execute for each server
    (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (assets.txt) do echo %command% %%f
        echo exit 
    ) > "%tempFile%"

    rem Connect to each of the servers sending the generated command list
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (clusters.txt) do (
        rcmd \\%%a < "%tempFile%"
    )

    del /f /q "%tempFile%" > nul 2>nul

    endlocal
```

Comment: Hello MC ND, the server is Windows server 2003. Thanks for putting this together for me, I'll go try it now. I'll let you know the results shortly.

Comment: `C:\Temp\Deletes>test.bat
Executing on \\sea80003-n0: cmd.exe /v:on /c set c=echo \vstrmkit\scp dir &!c!11E8A51A*&!c!11E8A51D*&!c!11E8A614*

'!c!11E8A51A*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Comment: Here it's what I get: `C:\Temp\Deletes>test.bat
Executing on \\sea80003-n0: cmd.exe /v:on /c set c=echo \vstrmkit\scp dir &!c!11E8A51A*&!c!11E8A51D*&!c!11E8A614*
'!c!11E8A51A*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` I changed the command to `scp dir` for safety measure.I want the following command to loop with every file, so if I have a list of 20 files then I need `scp del file1*` `scp del file2*` `scp del file3*` I need the star at the end of the file cus every file has 3 additional extension so it looks like this **file1 file1.vvx file1.fr file1.ff**

Comment: @pbesk18: there was a problem with the way rcmd handles some quotes. I've changed one line, that now looks `set "command=set c=%command% "` (upated in answer). I`ve installed rcmd (from Windows 2000 Resource Kit) over XP (the only thing i have at hand) and tried. Now it seems to work without problems, but it is not the same environment. Try now.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @MC ND: I'm trying now! This is what I'm getting: 
`C:\Temp\Deletes>test2.bat
Executing on \\sea80106-n0: cmd.exe /v:on /c set c=echo \vstrmkit\scp dir &!c!11e8A8B6*

'!c!11e8A8B6*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Remote server \\sea80106-n0 disconnected`

Comment: @pbesk18: My output goes `Executing on \\3ab6eea84f: cmd.exe /v:on /c "set c=echo \vstrmkit\scp del &!c!11E8A51A*&!c!11E8A51D*&!c!11E8A614*&!
c!11E88E4E*&!c!11E88E4C*"

\vstrmkit\scp del 11E8A51A*
\vstrmkit\scp del 11E8A51D*
\vstrmkit\scp del 11E8A614*
\vstrmkit\scp del 11E88E4E*
\vstrmkit\scp del 11E88E4C*

Remote server \\3ab6eea84f disconnected` I see it working, but quotes on my output that are not on yours. Is code the same? Some copy/paste problem?

Comment: Here it's what mine looks like:
`C:\Temp\Deletes>test2.bat
Executing on \\sea80106-n0: cmd.exe /v:on /c set c= \vstrmkit\scp dir &!c!11E85E6A*&!c!11E86EE5*

'!c!11E85E6A*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'!c!11E86EE5*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Remote server \\sea80106-n0 disconnected
`

Comment: @pbesk18: I don't know why my system keeps quotes but yours does not. OK. Next try. I've included in answer other way of doing it. It also works in my system. Hope it works in your system.

Comment: It works **MD**, your second option works nicely... Thank you very much, great job!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help.
I don't now for what you have an `*` after the file-name but it have to be removed by
the script. Or is that a `.*` ???

EDIT : IF you have various file with the same name and various ("Unknown") extensions then you have to test for the extensions with a new `FOR` loop :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('type clusters.txt') DO (
            FOR /F "tokens=*" %%B in ('type assets.txt') DO (
                     set $asset=%%B
                     rcmd.exe \\%%A \vstrmkit\scp del !$asset:~0,-1!.*))
```

Comment: I have an * after the filename because the filename have 3 additional files, so when I run this command [scp del 11E8A51A*] it deletes all the files 11E8A51A.ff 11E8A51A.fr 11E8A51A.vvx 11E8A51A. I will try this tomorrow when I get to work... I thank you so much for your help, I'll let you know tomorrow if it works. I need the star to be there so I can delete all of those files as well.

Comment: the command is looping with the file, however, rcmd is also looping and I don't need it to loop also I don't see !asset getting replaced by the asset filename. It connects then run `scp del !asset` then it disconnects and it connects again to go thru the next file on the list so it's doing to many reconnections, once it connects I need the `\vstrmkit\scp del !asset' to loop until it deletes all the assets in the list, then it will disconnect and go to the next server. I need the star for every file, 1 file has 4 different ext **(i.e: 11e8432a 11e8432a.ff 11e8432a.fr 11e8432a.vvx)**

Comment: Then my first solution should work. Test the new edit

Comment: here it's what I'm getting: `Executing on \\sea80003-n0: \vstrmkit\scp dir $asset:0,-1.*

SCP-E-SYNTAX, file "$asset:0,-1.*" not found, error VSTRM_INVALID_OBJECT_NAME

  Free Space:             2,333,834,477,568 (2225718 MB)
 Total Space:            10,975,219,548,160 (10466785 MB)` I made sure that those video files are on the videoserver. `C:\vstrmkit>scp dir 11e80fd0*

\SeaFileDevices\ files

 24-Apr-2012 04:41:07 PM      2,956,645,356  \SeaFileDevices\DVL\11E80FD0
 24-Apr-2012 04:41:11 PM        394,207,424  \SeaFileDevices\DVL\11E80FD0.ff`

Comment: Sorry I forgot the  ´~´ in the variable `!$asset:~0,-1!.*`. Corrected

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "filelist="
FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN (assets.txt) DO CALL SET filelist=%%filelist%% %%A
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (clusters.txt) DO echo rcmd \\%%A \vstrmkit\scp del %filelist%
GOTO :EOF
```

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO rcmd` to `rcmd` to execute the deletion

---

Possible solution if the command can't take multiple arguments:

Create a batch file called `delasset.bat` and copy it either into `\vstrmkit` on each target machine or some other directory on the `path` of each machine (eg `c:\windows` or `c:\windows\system32`)

delasset.bat should contain

```dos
@ECHO OFF
ECHO DEL %*
```

(Again, I've simply `ECHO`ed the `DEL` - you'd need to remove the `echo` after verifying to activate)

Then change `...rcmd \\%%A \vstrmkit\scp del %filelist%` to `...rcmd \\%%A \vstrmkit\scp DELASSET %filelist%`

(it's case-insensitive; I've UPPERCASED it for emphasis)

---

Another possible way:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "filelist="
FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN (assets.txt) DO CALL SET filelist=%%filelist%%:%%A
SET filelist=%filelist:~1%
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (clusters.txt) DO echo rcmd \\%%A \vstrmkit\scp del %filelist::=^&\vstrmkit\scp del %
GOTO :EOF
```

which should generate (eg)

```
rcmd \\SEA88630-N0 \vstrmkit\scp del 11E8A51A*&\vstrmkit\scp del 11E8A51D*&\vstrmkit\scp del 11E8A614*&\vstrmkit\scp del 11E88E4E*&\vstrmkit\scp del 11E88E4C*
```

Note that `filelist` is now built with colons separating the items. Colon cannot be part of a filename. The first character (which will be a colon, since `filelist` has `:filenamefromfile` appended to it) is then stripped off (see `set/?` from the prompt for substring documentation)

The hieroglypics in `%filelist::=^&\vstrmkit\scp del %` mean 'with filelist, substitute for (first `:`) [the characters between the first `:` and the `=` - which happens to be a colon] with the string `&\vstrmkit\scp del` (ie. all characters between the `=` and the closing `%` - with the additional modification that since `&` is a special character to cmd (it means 'do the thing before the `&`, then the thing after') the `&` needs to be "escaped" by a caret (`^`) which says "this is a special character that I want to use as an ordinary character".

Leaving the `echo` firmly in place will allow you to see precisely what should be delivered. Sadly, I've no idea whether it's correct...

Comment: Magoo, thanks for your help, tomorrow when I get to work I will test this, I'll let you know whether or not it worked, hopefully it will. Thanks again. I saw that you only used one Variable, is that a mistake?

Comment: Not at all. The first `for` loop builds each line from `assets.txt` into `filelist`, separated by spaces. The `call ..%%var%%...` syntax accesses the RUN-TIME value of `var` so the changes are cunulative. Once that `for` is complete, any reference to `%%A` is finished, too. The command issued would be `rcmd...del 11E8A51A* 11E8A51D* ...` - and that should work, since `del arg1 arg2...` deletes according to each `arg` delivered. Not sure how `rcmd` will feel about it though - never used it myself, hence the requirement for user-verification.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Magoo, pretty good explanation... the 'scp del' cmd has to be ran on every asset, it doesnt work with multiple files hence the 'scp del' 11E8A51A* (with the start it will delete 3 additional files with the same name but different extension) but to delete two totally diferent files with diffirent name I would need to run scp del file#1 and then scp del file#2 so scp del arg1 arg2 (if arg1 arg2... is the next new file on the list then I don't think it's going to work but I'll definitely try it. I need the command 'scp del' to loop with every file in the filelist.

Comment: I tested and yes the command can't take multiple arguments. here it's the results: `Remote server \\sea80174-n0 disconnected
Executing on \\sea80178-n0: \vstrmkit\scp dir 11E8A51A* 11E8A51D* 11E8A614* 11E88E4E* 11E88E4C* 11E88CE8* 11E88CDA* 11E88B67* 11E87027* 11E86FCF* 11E86F26* 11E86EDB*
SCP-E-SYNTAX, file "11E86EDB*" not found, error ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
  Free Space:                23,587,717,120 (22495 MB)` ... I want to avoid having to copy a fail over to 50 servers. So the first option didn't work, I'll try this one `rcmd \\SEA88630-N0 \vstrmkit\scp del 11E8A51A*` This might do it. thx!

Comment: The second option didn't work since scp can't execute `C:\Temp\Deletes>rcmd \\SEA80005-N0 \vstrmkit\scp dir 11E8A51A*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E8A51D*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E8A614*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E88E4E*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E88E4C*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E88CE8*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E88CDA*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E88B67*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E87027*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E86FCF*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E86F26*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E86EDB*
Executing on \\sea80005-n0: \vstrmkit\scp dir 11E8A51A*&\vstrmkit\scp dir 11E8A51D*&\vstrmkit\scp dir` I changed the command to `scp dir` to get a directory listing.

Comment: Without a manual for Seachange scp syntax, which doesn't seem to be on the net (I found a reference to a 'seachange server reference' manual, but no hits on the manual itself) I really have no idea what the acceptable commandset is. What is interesting is that the syntax error generated nominated the LAST entry on the list. Perhaps there were no files matching *THAT* particular mask and that's why it barfed. Can't tell from here. Perhaps remove the last `assets.txt` line and see what happens.

Comment: You are right **Magoo**, those files had already been deleted, I'll try with existing files to see what happens... Also, I'll try to get you an `scp /help guide` to see if you can determine it with this, thanks a lot for taking the time to help me get this working, it will be a great help seriously!

Comment: you are really a Mago (Magician) the second one worked... Thank you so much, I'm so happy for your help. It is working YESSS. Man I'm honestly impressed you pulled this one, I removed the echo to see how it works. I'll send you the snippet so you can see it. NICE :D Thank you so much again...

Comment: C:\Temp\Deletes>test.bat
C:\Temp\Deletes>SETLOCAL
C:\Temp\Deletes>SET "filelist="
C:\Temp\Deletes>FOR /F "delims=" %A IN (assets.txt) DO CALL SET filelist=%filelist%:%A
C:\Temp\Deletes>CALL SET filelist=%filelist%:11e8A8B6*
C:\Temp\Deletes>SET filelist=11e8A8B6*
C:\Temp\Deletes>FOR /F "tokens=*" %A IN (clusters.txt) DO rcmd \\%A \vstrmkit\scp del 11e8A8B6*

Comment: C:\Temp\Deletes>rcmd \\SEA80106-N0 \vstrmkit\scp del 11e8A8B6*
Executing on \\sea80106-n0: \vstrmkit\scp del 11e8A8B6*


\SeaFileDevices\ files deleted:

\SeaFileDevices\DVL\11E8A8B6
\SeaFileDevices\DVL\11E8A8B6.ff
\SeaFileDevices\DVL\11E8A8B6.ff1
\SeaFileDevices\DVL\11E8A8B6.ff3
\SeaFileDevices\DVL\11E8A8B6.fr
\SeaFileDevices\DVL\11E8A8B6.fr1
\SeaFileDevices\DVL\11E8A8B6.fr3
\SeaFileDevices\DVL\11E8A8B6.vvx
Total of 8 files deleted
Remote server \\sea80106-n0 disconnected
GOTO :EOF

Comment: unfortunately when I put more than 5 files on my assets.txt file the batch file doesn't work (it get stuck). Is there any way to fix this? Thanks...

Comment: This is all I got for scp del command `C:\Temp\Deletes>scp help del

  Deletes a file using Vstrm.

    scp delete file-spec`